# Detect Processor Affinity/Priority Change in .NET?

Tags: c#, java, .net, process, jar

I wrote a small executable in C# .NET that manages a .jar file. Our web software doesn't work with .jar files, so my program starts/stops/etc the Java application.

I need to be able to detect if the Processor Affinity or the Priority changes on my executable though so I can change in on the Java process. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to poll the system using a timer.  You'd also have to keep a `Process` object referring to the process running your .jar.  On each iteration, just set the other process's values to your current process's values

```
var myProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
jarProc = myProc.ProcessorAffinity;
jarProc = myProc.BasePriority;
jarProc = myProc.PriorityBoostEnabled;
```